# AS3: Static scope question

Tags: actionscript-3, static, scope

I've always found this interesting, and haven't managed to fully understand it yet. Take this class:

```
package
{
    public class SomeClass
    {
        private var _myvar:String = "hello";

        public static function sayHello():void
        {
            trace(_myvar);
        }
    }
}
```

As we know, this will throw an error unless I declare `_myvar` as `private static var _myvar`

> **1120:** Access of undefined property _myvar.

I don't completely understand why `_myvar` isn't in scope unless it's `static`. Can anyone provide a easy to understand explanation of this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As `_myvar` is not static it's a property that is attached to an instance of `SomeClass`, i.e. it has only meaning each time you create a new `SomeClass`.

In contrary a `static` property is attached to the Class object, it exists only once and is not dependent of each instance of SomeClass created.

So when you try to reach `_myvar` from your `static function sayHello` it's the same as calling `this._myvar` but you have **only one static** property and can have **multiple instance** created over the timelife of your application, what should be the value of `this` in that case ?

Comment: That makes more sense - because no instance of SomeClass has been created, _myvar doesn't exist / hasn't been created yet. Does that sound right?

Comment: @Marty Wallace, Yes that's it